# rJava - method with signature not found

Tags: java, r, java-native-interface, rjava, r-package

My problem is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066453/rjava-jcall-calling-issue-method-with-signature-not-found/44279812?noredirect=1#comment75570942_44279812) : 
Even with adding the semicolon didn't work for me this is my method when i call .jmethod to display it for me :

> [10] "public java.util.Set utils.Rinterface.getPhones()"

when I call the method, Like this

> rJava::.jcall(rinterface,"Ljava.util.Set;","getPhones")

I got this error :

> rJava::.jcall(rinterface, "Ljava.util.Set;", "getPhones") :    method
>   getPhones with signature ()Ljava.util.Set; not found it gives that
>   error, still don't know whats wrong ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this sample tree structure:

```
.
└── utils
    └── Rinterface.java
```

and with super simple class

```
package utils;

import java.util.Set;

public class Rinterface {
    public java.util.Set getPhones() {
        return new java.util.HashSet();
    }
}
```

make sure to compile it with the same Java version you are using with rJava.

Set up Java env

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
# note that you have to point to place where utils directory is
.jaddClassPath(dir("place_where_your_package_is",full.names=TRUE))
obj <- .jnew("utils.Rinterface")
# call method
result=.jcall(obj, returnSig="Ljava/util/Set;", method="getPhones")
```

you can always get the signature of method with

```
Compiled from "Rinterface.java"
public class utils.Rinterface {
  public utils.Rinterface();
    descriptor: ()V

  public java.util.Set getPhones();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/util/Set;
}
```

In my case, it works as expected.

***Update:***

in your case, you use:

`Ljava.util.Set;`

replace it with

`Ljava/util/Set;`

***Update:***

Updated to reflect proper package layout